# Replace class reference

Tags: c#, class, pointers, reference

I would like to know how you can change the reference of classes to another without changing all its references, example:
in C# using the unsafe pointer i can replace the Vertex1 with Vertex0 simply re-assign the address of struct:

```
class Program
{
    public struct Vertex 
    {
        public int data;
        public Vertex(int data) { this.data = data; }
        public override string ToString() { return data.ToString(); }
    }
    public unsafe struct Edge
    {
        public Vertex* v0, v1;
        public Face* f0, f1;
        public override string ToString() { return string.Format("e({0},{1})", (*v0), (*v1)); }
    }
    public unsafe struct Face
    {
        public Vertex* v0, v1, v2;
        public Edge* e01, e12, e20;
        public override string ToString() { return string.Format("f[{0},{1},{2}]", (*v0), (*v1), (*v2)); }
    }

    public unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // assign address of vertex
        Vertex P0 = new Vertex(0);
        Vertex P1 = new Vertex(1);
        Vertex P2;

        Face FA = new Face { v0 = &P0, v1 = &P1, v2 = &P2 };
        Face FB = new Face { v0 = &P0, v1 = &P2, v2 = &P1 };
        Edge e01 = new Edge { v0 = &P0, v1 = &P1 };
        Edge e12 = new Edge { v0 = &P1, v1 = &P2 };
        Edge e20 = new Edge { v0 = &P2, v1 = &P0 };
        //link face -> edge
        e01.f0 = &FA; e01.f1 = &FB;
        e12.f0 = &FA; e12.f1 = &FB;
        e20.f0 = &FA; e20.f1 = &FB;
        //link edge -> face
        FA.e01 = &e01; FA.e12 = &e12; FA.e20 = &e20;
        FB.e01 = &e20; FA.e12 = &e12; FA.e20 = &e01;

        // example : collapse P0 to P1
        Vertex* p0 = &P0;
        *p0 = P1;

        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
}
```

Using Class instead Struct this don't work because if i want change Vertex1 with Vertex0 i need to assign Vertex0 in ALL properties (so for each face and for each edges).
P0 = P1 change only P0 value, not all references in faces and edges classes.

The code work but using pointers make code very complicated. Define ad array of pointers (Vertex*[] v) can't be done because visual studio say "i can't get the size of struct"...
etc...

Comment: You haven't described what higher level problem you're trying to solve. Do you really need unsafe code at all? This looks like C# code written in a C++ accent at the moment. If you can describe the wider problem you're trying to address, we can help you with a more appropriate design.

Comment: @JonSkeet In the code write with unsafe pointers i can "replace" all Vertex1 with Vertex0 in all faces and edges structs simply to target address of Vertex1 to Vertex0... this change all Vertex1 to Vertex0 in FA, FB, e01, e12 and e20. If i use Class instead Struct i need to replace FA.v1 = P0, FB.v2 = P0 , e01.v1 = P0 etcc... but need to search it to replace and this is very espansive with many many faces and edges...

Comment: That's just repeating what you've already stated - it doesn't give us a higher-level indication of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: How do the same with "Class" ?